# Kafka AVRO - conversion from long to datetime

Tags: apache-kafka, deserialization, avro, confluent-platform

I get the following error when I want to send an AVRO message which contains a field that has the type long:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 61
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I use Confluent 3.2.0 and Apache Spark 2.2.0. This error is thrown in a Spark Job which processes AVRO messages and prints them in a console. In the AVRO schema, the corresponding field is defined like this:

```
{\"name\": \"event_time\", \"type\": { \"type\" : \"long\", \"logicalType\": \"timestamp-millis\"}}
```

In the Java class generated from the `.avsc` file, the field is defined as below:

```
private DateTime event_time;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue using Confluent 4.0.0 and Avro 1.8.2.  I had a stream processor that was attempting to convert a long to a DateTime.  I overcame the issue by adding the correct conversion.  Before I begin any processing logic, I used the  [Specific Data](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificData.html) static utilities class and adding the correct Logical type conversion.

```
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
```

Comment: can you demonstrate you used this?

Comment: It needs to be used in Main object, wherever the applicaton starts.

Answer (score 3):

In Avro 1.9.X and above, the symbol `TimestampConversion` is not present anymore. replacing the above from @user3222582 with `TimestampMillisConversion` fixed a compilation error for me with avro 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the version of avro to 1.9.X in avro dependency and avro-maven-plugin in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
                <!--<goal>idl-protocol</goal>-->
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                <stringType>String</stringType>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also make sure to delete previously generated class from AVRO schema and do mvn compile.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are configuring a SpecificAvroSerde you can set `AVRO_USE_LOGICAL_TYPE_CONVERTERS_CONFIG` to `true`:

```java
final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
serdeConfig.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "mock://schema-registry-url");
serdeConfig.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.AVRO_USE_LOGICAL_TYPE_CONVERTERS_CONFIG, true);

final SpecificAvroSerde<T> serde = SpecificAvroSerde<>();
serde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

Please note that the config is called KafkaAvro**Serializer**Config.AVRO_USE_LOGICAL_TYPE_CONVERTERS_CONFIG, but it is also used for the serdes deserializer.