# Avro: Unknown datum type org.joda.time.DateTime for nullable Timestamp field

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams

When a field of type Timestamp is nullable, serialization fails(trace and schema below) and the error disappears after changing the field to mandatory. Please help understand the issue.

**Error**:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type org.joda.time.DateTime: 2011-06-07T00:00:00.000Z
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getSchemaName(GenericData.java:757)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchemaName(SpecificData.java:314)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:721)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65)
```

**Schema**

```
{
  "name": "shipdate",
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "long",
      "connect.version": 1,
      "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
      "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
    }
  ],
  "default": null
}
```

**ENVIRONMENT**

- Java 1.8
- Apache maven 3.5.2
- Avro 1.8.2 also tested with 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT
- avro-maven-plugin
- kafka-streams 2.0.0-cp1

Comment: I see the same problem.  I do not see the problem if the Timestamp field is not nullable.

Comment: It is a known issue with Avro as of 1.8.2, the work around is to use Union [null, long] as a datatype in that case

Comment: ftr: same error might occur with 1.8.1. fix is the same as for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867866/kafka-avro-conversion-from-long-to-datetime/49329318#49329318

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar Can you please provide the code snippet that you have used