# Avro serialization problem in case of optional logicalType

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I don't have any experience with kafka and related technology, so I need your help.

I am facing following problem:

In my current project we use confluent platform (kafka + schema registry). For serialization/deserialization we decided to use AVRO.

I created springboot application which behaves as producer and also consumer of kafka messages.

I have a problem, when i try to send kafka message which contains field `shippedAt` ... In the schema it is defined as a optional field (default: null)

When I try to send message into kafka, producer throws an exception: `org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type java.time.Instant: 2023-12-18T10:40:01.594Z`

Do you have similar experience? Or is there a better way how to work with timestamps?

Schema for message (field is mandatory):

```json
{
  "namespace": "sk.kubbo.eventhubpoc.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Order",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "orderId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "product",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "quantity",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "shippedAt",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type java.time.Instant: 2023-12-18T10:40:01.594Z
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getSchemaName(GenericData.java:947) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchemaName(SpecificData.java:440) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:906) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:307) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:157) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:108) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:234) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeRecord(SpecificDatumWriter.java:92) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:145) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:95) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:159) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:95) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:82) ~[avro-1.11.3.jar:1.11.3]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.writeDatum(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:192) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:162) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:68) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1000) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:947) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:787) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.observeSend(KafkaTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:545) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at sk.kubbo.eventhubpoc.producer.EventProducer.sendMessage(EventProducer.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sk.kubbo.eventhubpoc.producer.EventProducer.createOrderEvent(EventProducer.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sk.kubbo.eventhubpoc.controller.ProducerController.produceOrder(ProducerController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:76) ~[logbook-servlet-3.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:32) ~[logbook-servlet-3.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

It works correctly, if value of `shippedAt` is `null`. Also when i modify schema and make the field `shippedAt` mandatory (see snippet bellow), it works correctly.

```
{
  "namespace": "sk.kubbo.eventhubpoc.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Order",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "orderId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "product",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "quantity",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "shippedAt",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For generating java classes I use maven plugin `org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3` and my settings looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/event</sourceDirectory>
        <createSetters>false</createSetters>
        <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
        <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I noticed that when I generate java class from schema2 (field is mandatory) in the generated class there is method getConversion (this is missing in the generated class when field is optional)

```
  private static final org.apache.avro.Conversion<?>[] conversions =
      new org.apache.avro.Conversion<?>[] {
      null,
      null,
      null,
      new org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions.TimestampMillisConversion(),
      null
  };

  @Override
  public org.apache.avro.Conversion<?> getConversion(int field) {
    return conversions[field];
  }
```

It looks that it can be caused by having multiple event types in one topic. I implemented it like in the article https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/
When I use my `order` class in topic which allows only `order` messages, it works.

I am really desperate now, since we need to have multiple event types in one topic, because we have to preserve order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve the issue.

I found an information ([Writing Avro From Spark to Kafka](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kafka-sink-spark-avro-deepak-dabi/)) that it is a bug in avro dependencies. On this page was also a link to [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867866/kafka-avro-conversion-from-long-to-datetime/49329318#49329318) where I found the solution

I added following line in the application class and now it works correctly

```
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampMillisConversion());
```